# Prepare part of prepared statement failing - directly under another prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following prepare of a prepared statement that is failing...

```
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `topic_id`=?");
    //var_dump($stmt2);
    if ( !$stmt2 || !empty($con->error)) {
        die('Select forum posts prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
```

I have almost the exact same prepare in my first prepared statement and it goes through just fine. I am not sure if the fact that I have two prepared statements right after each other if this is causing an issue or what the case may be?

Right now I get this error...

-Select forum posts prepare() failed:-

That the prepare failed error from the code above.

Does anyone see anything that would be causing this to fail?

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$cid = $_GET['cid'];
$tid = $_GET['tid'];
$userid = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );

//Prepared SELECT stmt to get forum topics
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_topics WHERE `category_id`=? AND id=? LIMIT 1");
if (!$stmt || $con->error ) {
    die('Select topics prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
}
if(!$stmt->bind_param('ii', $cid, $tid)) {
    die('Select topics bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    die('Select topics execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
if($numrows == 1){
    echo "<table width='100%'>";
    if ( $_SESSION['user'] ) { 
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Add Reply' onClick=\"window.location = 
    'forum_post_reply.php?cid=".$cid."$tid=".$tid."'\"> <hr />";
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><p>Please log in to add your reply</p><hr /></td></tr>";
    }
    foreach($stmt as $row) {

        //Prepared SELECT stmt to get forum posts
        $stmt2 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE `category_id`=? AND `topic_id`=?");
        //var_dump($stmt2);
        if ( !$stmt2 || !empty($con->error)) {
            die('Select forum posts prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
        }
        //var_dump($con->error);
        if(!$stmt2->bind_param('ii', $cid, $tid)) {
            die('Select forum posts bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
        }
        if(!$stmt2->execute()) {
            die('Select forum posts execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
        }
        //while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt2)){
        foreach($stmt2 as $row2) {  
            echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>
            <div style='min-height: 125px;'>".$row['topic_title']."<br />
            by ".$row2['post_creator']." - " .$row2['post_date']. "<hr />" . $row2['post_content'] ."</div></td>
            <td width='200' valign='top' align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>User Info Here!</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan='2'><hr /></td></tr>";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>This topic does not exist.</p>";
}
```

UPDATE - Possible INNER JOIN, like this?

```
//Prepared SELECT stmt to get forum topics
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum_topics AS f INNER JOIN forum_posts AS p ON
 f.category_id=p.category_id ON f.id=p.topic_id WHERE s.category_id=? AND s.id=? LIMIT 1");
if (!$stmt || $con->error ) {
    die('Select topics prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
}
if(!$stmt->bind_param('ii', $cid, $tid)) {
    die('Select topics bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    die('Select topics execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
if($numrows == 1){
    echo "<table width='100%'>";
    if ( $_SESSION['user'] ) { 
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Add Reply' onClick=\"window.location = 
    'forum_post_reply.php?cid=".$cid."$tid=".$tid."'\"> <hr />";
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><p>Please log in to add your reply</p><hr /></td></tr>";
    }
    foreach($stmt as $row) {
            echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>
            <div style='min-height: 125px;'>".$row['topic_title']."<br />
            by ".$row2['post_creator']." - " .$row2['post_date']. "<hr />" . $row2['post_content'] ."</div></td>
            <td width='200' valign='top' align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>User Info Here!</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan='2'><hr /></td></tr>";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>This topic does not exist.</p>";
}

}*/
/*$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT topic_title, post_content FROM forum_topics, forum_posts 
WHERE forum_topics.category_id=forum_posts.category_id 
AND forum_topics.category_id=?");*/
//$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT topic_title, topic_creator FROM forum_posts AS f LEFT JOIN forum_topics AS p ON f.category_id=p.category_id WHERE f.category_id=?");
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT topic_title, topic_creator FROM forum_posts AS p, forum_topics AS f WHERE f.category_id=? AND p.topic_id=? LIMIT 1");
if (!$stmt || $con->error ) { 
die('Select forum prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error)); 
} 
if(!$stmt->bind_param('ii', $cid, $tid)) { 
die('Select forum bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error)); 
}
if(!$stmt->execute()) { 
die('Select forum execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error)); 
}
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $post_content, $topic_title); 
$stmt->store_result(); 
echo $stmt->store_result(); 
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows; 
if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
echo "<table width='100%'>";
if ( $_SESSION['user'] ) {
    echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Add Reply' onClick=\"window.location =
'forum_post_reply.php?cid=".$cid."$tid=".$tid."'\"> <hr />";
} else {
    echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><p>Please log in to add your reply</p><hr /></td></tr>";
}
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'> 
<div style='min-height: 125px;'>".$topic_title."<br /> 
by " . $post_content ."</div></td> 
<td width='200' valign='top' align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>User Info Here!</td></tr> 
<tr><td colspan='2'><hr /></td></tr>";
} 
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); 
} else { 
echo "<p>This topic does not exist.</p>"; 
}

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83776/discussion-on-question-by-paul-prepare-part-of-prepared-statement-failing-dire).

Answer (score 2):

After spending 5 hours with OP in chat, finally solve the issues

Problems;

- 2nd Query failing
- with 1st Query result not showing

No Need;

- No need to Join tables
- No need of 2nd Select Query
- No foreach

Solution;

```
//bind the result
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $topic_title, $topic_creator, $postDate, $postcontent);
//use while loop instead foreach
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
```

Working code;

```
//Prepared SELECT stmt to get forum topics
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT topic_title, topic_creator, post_date, post_content FROM forum_posts AS p, forum_topics AS f WHERE f.category_id=? AND p.topic_id=?");
if (!$stmt || $con->error ) {
    die('Select forum prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
}
if(!$stmt->bind_param('ii', $cid, $tid)) {
    die('Select forum bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
if(!$stmt->execute()) {
    die('Select forum execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $topic_title, $topic_creator, $postDate, $postcontent);
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows > 0){

    echo "<table width='100%'>";
    if ( $_SESSION['user'] ) { 
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Add Reply' onClick=\"window.location = 
    'forum_post_reply.php?cid=".$cid."$tid=".$tid."'\"> <hr />";
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><p>Please log in to add your reply</p><hr /></td></tr>";
    }
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>
        <div style='min-height: 125px;'>".$topic_title."<br />
        by ".$topic_creator." - " .$postDate. "<hr />" . $postcontent ."</div></td>
        <td width='200' valign='top' align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>User Info Here!</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan='2'><hr /></td></tr>";
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
} else {
    echo "<p>This topic does not exist.</p>";
}
```

Forget to mention, this is my first time with mysqli, i read about it but never tried before.

Comment: After I got home and actually looked at it, it still wasn't right. It is not getting the right post. It is only displaying the first post in the loop. I added back the `LIMIT`. \

Comment: Not sure I hope so. I just added my code to my original question at the bottom. It is very messy, but I commented out what I'm not using.

Comment: Yea, it looks like it, but I was so worried about getting something to output I didn't put two and two together. If I click on topic, I get all the posts, rather than just the posts that go along with that topic.

Comment: then thats another issue may be your next query where you are trying to open the topic, the chat link is still active, lets call it today and tomorrow will look at the topic thing and please do not add all the code in your question it will be get deleted by moderator and also delete all the comments from here, i m doing the same